copy row from one google sheet to another if it match the criteria yes and add comments in destination sheet
I have two sheets as below
MASTER
DESTINATION
From master sheet, I need to copy the data (col1 to col23) to destination sheet if I type yes and I need to add comments (col24) in the destination sheet. I have found a solution using query and importrange function to achieve this.
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/"),"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18,Col19,Col20,Col21,Col22,Col23  where Col23 = 'YES'",1)

but if I select NO after I copy the data to destination sheet, the comments in destination file are getting misaligned due to this.

Welcome to stack overflow. Share the spreadsheet or at least the screenshot so that moderator would be able to replicate where the issue is coming from.

It sounds like your intention is to manually add data side-by-side with formula results. As you note, that exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.
One way to avoid the issue would be to insert the new column to the existing data table instead of adding it next to formula results in another tab. Use Google Sheets features such as Data > Create a filter, filter views or a table with Group by view instead copying data to the other tab.
If you absolutely need to work in two tabs, use vlookup() to look up the data from yet another table by some unique key you have in all the tables. If you choose to go this route, note that you shouldn't use importrange() to copy data from one tab to another within the same spreadsheet file. Use an { array expression } instead.
See this thorough treatment of the row misalignment issue.
